# OSGI netstat like command

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have an OSGI container with several TCP/UDP ports open,
is there any way to map an open port to a bundle using OSGI tools?

furthermore, if some bundle registers itself as an HTTP servlet, can I query somehow to know what is already registered and belongs to each bundle?

Answer (score 0):

With Karaf you have a couple of commands available (GOGO-shell) that will help you on what servlet or war is registered

```
web:list
```

or

```
http:list
```

regarding the TCP ports, there is nothing available for this yet, though I'm sure this can be achieved programmatically and put into a custom command if needed. The shell-commands are easy to write with Karaf.

```
@Command(scope = "tcp", name = "netstat", description = "Show TCP connections, open ports")
@Service
public class NetStat extends implements Action {

@Option(name = "-n", aliases = { "--name" }, description = "Show only name", required = false, multiValued = false)
private Boolean named;

@Argument(name = "someArgument", description = "Some other argument", required = false, multiValued = false)
private String argument;

@Override
public Object doExecute() throws Exception {
... your code here ...
}
```